# Using try/catch makes it so I can't use the variable outside of the try/catch block

Tags: c#, try-catch, scope

I have a code that gets a `Product` object from a web service. If there is no product, it returns an `EntityDoesNotExist` exception. I need to handle this.. However, I have a lot of other code that deals with the returned `Product`, but if this code is not within the try/catch, it doesn't work because `Product` is basically not defined.  Is the only way to make this work to include my other related code within the try/catch? This seems really sloppy.

Code example:

```
try {
    Product product = catalogContext.GetProduct("CatalogName", "ProductId");

} catch(EntityDoesNotExist e) {
    // Do something here
}

if(dataGridView1.InvokeRequired) {
    // Do something in another thread with product
}
```

Comment: How do you access the `product` outside of the try-catch if it's _declared_ **in** it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just declare it outside the try/catch scope.

```
Product product;
try
{
    product = catalogContext.GetProduct("CatalogName", "ProductId");
}
catch (EntityDoesNotExist e)
{
    product = null;
}

if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
{
    // use product here
}
```

Comment: Using this, afterward I try to do `MessageBox.Show(p.SomeProperty)` and it says: Use of unassigned local variable 'p'

Comment: @StephenKnoth you must either assign `product` some value before the `try` (e.g. `Product product = null;`), or in the `catch` (as this solution has), or have the `catch` always `throw` again, not *only* assign it in the `try`. Things in the `try` are treated as if they might run, not as if they will run, so `p` might be unassigned in that context.

Answer (score 2):

If an exception was thrown when fetching your product then you don't have a product to act on.  It seems that you should be ensuring that you only execute the UI code if you didn't throw an exception.  That can be done by moving that code *inside* the `try` block:

```
try
{
    Product product = catalogContext.GetProduct("CatalogName", "ProductId");

    if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Do something in another thread with product
    }
}
catch (EntityDoesNotExist e)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only way to make this work to include my other related code
>   within the try/catch?

No. Even though an `EntityDoesNotExist` exception is thrown if the webservice does not return a `Product`, you need to declare your local `Product` variable outside of the try block so that your related code outside of the try block can access it.

Declare `product` outside of the `try{}catch{}`:

```
Product product = null;

try 
{        
    product = catalogContext.GetProduct("CatalogName", "ProductId");    
} 
catch(EntityDoesNotExist e) 
{
    // Do something here
}

if(dataGridView1.InvokeRequired) 
{
    // Do something in another thread with product
}
```